# Как в textwatcher сделать вводимое значение с заглавной буквы?

Tags: android, android-edittext

моя попытка такая:

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.d("qwer", "onTextChanged: " + s + " " + start + " " + before + " " + count);

            String originalText = s.toString();
            int originalTextLength = originalText.length();
            int currentSelection = textHeading.getSelectionStart();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean hasChanged = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < originalTextLength; i++) {
                char currentChar = originalText.charAt(i);
                if (isAllowed(currentChar) && i < 21) {
                    if (i == 0){
                        String str = "" + currentChar;
                        str.toUpperCase();
                        sb.append(str);
                    }
                    sb.append(currentChar);
                } else {
                    hasChanged = true;
                    if (currentSelection >= i) {
                        textHeading.setError("Please insert current letters");
                        currentSelection--;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hasChanged) {
                String newText = sb.toString();
                textHeading.setText(newText);
                textHeading.setSelection(currentSelection);
            }
        }
```

как видно очень тупенько проверяю индекс i и тупо делаю аперкейс, но не работает так как надо. а надо чтобы юзер как только ввел первую букву и сразу поменялась первая буква на заглавную, а дальше если даже он будет вводить заглавные, то наоборот делать прописные. Проблема еще в том, что если сетить в edittext  новые данные то получается бесконечный цикл так как срабатывает  listener  и метод onTextChanged перезапускается  и так до бесконечности..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из решений без использования "textwatcher":
в разметке поля добавить - android:inputType="textCapWords"

Может подойдет?

```html
public class TWatcherPhone implements TextWatcher {
    public EditText editText;
    Activity activ;
    int length;
    int maxLen;
    char firstChar;
    char lastChar;

    public TWatcherPhone(Activity activ, EditText et) {
        super();
        this.activ = activ;
        this.editText = et;
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        length = editText.getText().length();
        if (length > 0) {
            firstChar = editText.getText().charAt(0);
            maxLen = firstChar == '8' ? 11 : 13;
            lastChar = editText.getText().charAt(length - 1);
            if (length > maxLen) {
                String str = editText.getText().subSequence(0, maxLen).toString();
                editText.setText("");
                editText.append(str);
                ShowMessage(activ, "Превышение длины строки!\nМаксимально: " + maxLen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, Gravity.CENTER);
            } else {
                if ((length == 1 && (lastChar == '+' || lastChar == '8')) || (length > 1 && lastChar >= '0' && lastChar <= '9')) {
                    pr("Ok");
                } else {
                    ShowMessage(activ, "\"" + lastChar + "\"  - недопустимый символ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, Gravity.CENTER);
                    String str = editText.getText().subSequence(0, editText.getText().length() - 1).toString();
                    editText.setText("");
                    editText.append(str);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
}
```

Comment: именно надо в textwatcher((

Comment: Тогда пробуйте:     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {} вместо вашего метода: public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

Comment: Посмотрите я выше в ответ вставил код, который вводит телефонный номер. Преобразуйте логику под свои цели.

Comment: Вызывал данный код я таким образом:
        etTwoEditText2.setText("");
        TWatcherPhone inputWatcherPhone= new TWatcherPhone(activity, etTwoEditText2);
        etTwoEditText2.addTextChangedListener(inputWatcherPhone);